# Excel Max size for a cell

Tags: excel, charactercount

Is there any way to extend the character limit in a column?

I've around 800 number of URLs' which I want to put in a single column but due to some reason it's exceeding and going into another row.

Is it possible to extend character limit so it stick to one row?

[image: Blockquote]

Comment: If you can’t increase that limit, then use an if() statement that looks at the cell n+1 and if it does not start withh “www” or “htt” then concatenate it with the previous cell n ...

Comment: From the screenshot, did you mean "going into another Row" or "going into another Column"?  Also, are you splitting your URLs up with Tab characters?  (Because Excel will read that as "Move everything after this to the next column")

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want your information to be split over different rows, you can change the cell formatting: Alignment, Text Control, Wrap text => disable.

If you don't want your text to be written across different columns, you can just put a space in the next cell.

If you want to put more than 32767 characters inside one cell: I don't think this is possible, as mentioned in following URL:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

> Total number of characters that a cell can contain   32,767 characters

In that case I'd advise you to write some VBA in order to split your information over different cells.